# Create a simplified version of/interface to a more complex directive in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a rather complex modal dialog directive that includes some child directives, transclusion, isolated scope.  Here is an example of what it looks like:

```
<dm-modal reference="previewDialog" additional-class="datasourcePreview">
    <dm-modal-header><div class="dialog-title" ng-controller="dsPreviewCtrl">Preview of {{previewData.dataSourceName}}</div> </dm-modal-header>
    <dm-modal-body>
        <div ng-controller="dsPreviewCtrl" ng-include="dsPreview.html'" ></div>
    </dm-modal-body>
    <dm-modal-footer>
        Choose one
    </dm-modal-footer>
    <dm-modal-footer-buttons>
          <dm-modal-footer-button type="done" ng-click="doSomething()"></dm-modal-footer-button>
          <dm-modal-footer-button type="delete"></dm-modal-footer-button>
    </dm-modal-footer-buttons>
</dm-modal>
```

When using this directive, 80%+ of the time I only need to fiddle with a couple things because it's just a confirm dialog, and the rest of the options are standard.  Rather than a hairy interface that looks like the above, I'd like to implement a directive that would look like the following, but ultimately just produce the directive above.

```
<dm-simple-modal reference="confirmDialog" title="Are you sure?" okClick="handleOk()">
    <div ng-controller="dsPreviewCtrl" ng-include="'dsPreview.html'"></div>
</dm-simple-modal>
```

So it seems simplest to me to basically transform the above markup into the full markup for the other "more complete" directive which would look like the following:

```
<dm-modal reference="confirmDialog">
    <dm-modal-header>
        Are you sure?
    </dm-modal-header>
    <dm-modal-body>
        <div ng-controller="dsPreviewCtrl" ng-include="'dsPreview.html'"></div>
    </dm-modal-body>
    <dm-modal-footer-buttons>
          <dm-modal-footer-button text="Yes" ng-click="handleOk()"></dm-modal-footer-button>
          <dm-modal-footer-button type="No"></dm-modal-footer-button>
    </dm-modal-footer-buttons>
</dm-modal>
```

And then angular would compile this directive into the working html.

Putting this problem into a more contrived, but simpler example, I have created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/josepheames/JEYJa/1/

I even included an attempt to make the simpler directive using a template patterned after the more complex directive but I cannot get that to work.

the directives in this fiddle look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-click="doClick()">
    <complex-directive handle="complexDir" titleColor="blue">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    </complex-directive>

    <simple-directive handle="simpleDir" title="another {{title}}" color="red" />
</div>
```

And the working complex directive is this:

```
myApp.directive('complexDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            handle: '='
        },
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.handle= {
                doSomething: function() {
                    element.css('background-color', attr.titlecolor);
                }
            }                
        }
    }
});
```

And my failing attempt at a simple directive is this:

```
myApp.directive('simpleDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            handle: '='
        },
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<complex-directive handle="{{thehandle}}" titleColor="{{color}}"><h1>{{title}}</h1></complex-directive>',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.thehandle = attr.handle,
            scope.color = attr.titlecolor,
            scope.title = element.html(),
            scope.handle= {
                doSomething: function() {
                    element.css('background-color', attr.titlecolor);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Joe, you might find Ben Nadel's [nested directives](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2471-Delegating-Nested-Directive-Behavior-To-Parent-Directive-In-AngularJS.htm) post helpful here. I'm not certain it is a direct solution to your problem but he basically uses the technique to avoid a clutter of variant directive names, and to help with code re-use.